# Oracle error when deleting row: ... is mutating, trigger/function may not see

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

Trying to delete a row from `assessment_flaw` results in the following error:

> ORA-04091: table IN120032.ASSESSMENT_FLAW is mutating, trigger/function may not see it ORA-06512: at "IN120032.GEN_IDS_ASSESSMENT", line 22 ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'IN120032.GEN_IDS_ASSESSMENT' ORA-06512: at "IN120032.GEN_IDS_ASSESSMENT_FLAW", line 12 ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'IN120032.GEN_IDS_ASSESSMENT_FLAW'

What I'm not understanding is that, inserting rows into that table works fine while deleting them clearly doesn't.

Here's my sql script:

```
-- SEQUENCE

--drop sequence ids;
create sequence ids;

-- TABLES
drop view vehicle_view;
drop view assessment_view;
drop view assessment_flaw_view;
drop table assessment_flaw;
drop table flaw;
drop table assessment;
drop table vehicle;
drop table customer;

create table customer (
    id number(4) primary key,
    name varchar(50),
    street varchar(100),
    zip varchar(5),
    city varchar(100),
    phone varchar(15)
);

create table vehicle (
    id number(4) primary key,
    customer_id number(4) references customer,
    brand varchar(100),
    model varchar(100),
    year number(4),
    mileage number(10),
    weight number(4),
    brakepower number(4)
);

create view vehicle_view as
    select vehicle.id as "Id",
        customer.name as "Customer",
        vehicle.brand as "Brand",
        vehicle.model as "Model",
        vehicle.year as "Year",
        vehicle.mileage as "Mileage",
        vehicle.weight as "Weight",
        vehicle.brakepower as "Brakepower"
    from vehicle, customer
    where vehicle.customer_id = customer.id;

create table assessment (
    id number(4) primary key,
    vehicle_id number(4) references vehicle,
    datum date default sysdate,
    editor varchar(100),
    result number(4) default 0,
    flaws number(4) default 0,
    brakepower number(4,2) default 0
);

create view assessment_view as
    select assessment.id as "Id",
        vehicle_view."Customer" as "Customer",
        vehicle_view."Brand" as "Brand",
        vehicle_view."Model" as "Model",
        assessment.datum as "Date",
        assessment.editor as "Editor",
        assessment.result as "Result",
        assessment.flaws as "Flaws",
        assessment.brakepower as "Brakepower"
    from assessment, vehicle_view
    where assessment.vehicle_id = vehicle_view."Id";

create table flaw (
    id number(4) primary key,
    description varchar(100),
    rank number(4)
);

create table assessment_flaw (
    id number(4) primary key,
    assessment_id number(4) references assessment,
    flaw_id number(4) references flaw
);


create view assessment_flaw_view as
    select assessment_flaw.id as "Id",
        assessment_view."Customer" as "Customer",
        assessment_view."Brand" as "Brand",
        assessment_view."Model" as "Model",
        assessment_view."Editor" as "Editor",
        assessment_view."Result" as "Result",
        assessment_view."Flaws" as "Flaws",
        flaw.description as "Flaw",
        flaw.rank as "Flaw rank"
    from assessment_view, flaw, assessment_flaw
    where assessment_flaw.assessment_id = assessment_view."Id" and assessment_flaw.flaw_id = flaw.id;

-- TRIGGERS
create or replace trigger gen_ids_customer
before insert or update of id on customer
for each row
declare
    n number;
begin
    select ids.nextval into n from dual;
    if inserting then
        :new.id := n;
    elsif updating and :new.id != :old.id then
        raise_application_error(-20002, 'ID ist unveraenderlich konstant !!!');
    end if;
end;
/

create or replace trigger gen_ids_vehicle
before insert or update of id on vehicle
for each row
declare
    n number;
begin
    select ids.nextval into n from dual;
    if inserting then
        :new.id := n;
    elsif updating and :new.id != :old.id then
        raise_application_error(-20002, 'ID ist unveraenderlich konstant !!!');
    end if;
end;
/

create or replace trigger gen_ids_assessment
before insert or update on assessment
for each row
declare
    n number;
    bp assessment.brakepower%type;
    tmp number;
begin
    if inserting then
        select ids.nextval into n from dual;
        -- id
        :new.id := n;

        -- brakepower
        select ROUND(vehicle.weight / vehicle.brakepower,2) into bp from vehicle where vehicle.id = :new.vehicle_id;
        :new.brakepower := bp;
    elsif updating then
        if :new.id != :old.id then
            raise_application_error(-20002, 'ID ist unveraenderlich konstant !!!');
        end if;

        -- ok?
        dbms_output.put_line('gen_assessment_result before ok?');
        :new.result := 1;
        select COUNT(*) into tmp from assessment_flaw, flaw where assessment_flaw.assessment_id = :new.id and assessment_flaw.flaw_id = flaw.id and flaw.rank = 1;
        if tmp > 2 then
            :new.result := -1;
        end if;
        select COUNT(*) into tmp from assessment_flaw, flaw where assessment_flaw.assessment_id = :new.id and assessment_flaw.flaw_id = flaw.id and flaw.rank != 1;
        if tmp > 0  then
            :new.result := -1;
        end if;
        dbms_output.put_line('gen_assessment_result after ok?');
    end if;
end;
/

create or replace trigger gen_ids_flaw
before insert or update of id on flaw
for each row
declare
    n number;
begin
    select ids.nextval into n from dual;
    if inserting then
        :new.id := n;
    elsif updating and :new.id != :old.id then
        raise_application_error(-20002, 'ID ist unveraenderlich konstant !!!');
    end if;
end;
/

create or replace trigger gen_ids_assessment_flaw
before insert or delete or update on assessment_flaw
for each row
declare
    n number;
begin
    if inserting then
        select ids.nextval into n from dual;
        :new.id := n;

        dbms_output.put_line('flaws-count++ on assessment ' || :new.assessment_id);
        update assessment set assessment.flaws = assessment.flaws + 1 where assessment.id = :new.assessment_id;
    elsif deleting then
        dbms_output.put_line('flaws-count-- on assessment ' || :new.assessment_id);
        update assessment set assessment.flaws = assessment.flaws - 1 where assessment.id = :old.assessment_id;
    elsif updating then
        raise_application_error(-20002, 'Entitaet ist unveraenderlich konstant !!!');
    end if;
end;
/

-- INSERTS

insert into flaw(description, rank) values('Achseneinstellung nicht korrekt', 2);
insert into flaw(description, rank) values('Lichterfehlfunktion', 1);
insert into flaw(description, rank) values('Bremsscheiben abgenutzt', 3);
insert into flaw(description, rank) values('Becker auf der Windschutzscheibe', 1);

insert into customer(name, street, zip, city, phone) values('Simon Lammer', 'Str. 4', 4563, 'Micheldorf', '0680/12345431');
insert into customer(name, street, zip, city, phone) values('David Chen', 'Sonstige-Str. 42', 1234, 'Linz', '1234/9876555');
insert into customer(name, street, zip, city, phone) values('Jakob Woegerbauer', 'Gute-Str. 2', 9876, 'Schoenstadt', '9876/1234567');

insert into vehicle(customer_id, brand, model, year, mileage, weight, brakepower) values((select id from customer where customer.name like 'Simon Lammer'), 'Tesla', 'Model S', 2012, 5000, 2100, 1700);
insert into vehicle(customer_id, brand, model, year, mileage, weight, brakepower) values((select id from customer where customer.name like 'Simon Lammer'), 'Jeep', 'Wrangler', 1993, 1750645, 1480, 1300);
insert into vehicle(customer_id, brand, model, year, mileage, weight, brakepower) values((select id from customer where customer.name like 'David Chen'), 'Golf', 'GTI', 2001, 349256, 810, 530);
insert into vehicle(customer_id, brand, model, year, mileage, weight, brakepower) values((select id from customer where customer.name like 'Jakob Woegerbauer'), 'Aston Martin', 'V8 Vantage', 2007, 491274, 1695, 1200);

insert into assessment(vehicle_id, editor) values((select vehicle.id from vehicle, customer where vehicle.customer_id = customer.id and customer.name like 'Simon Lammer' and vehicle.model = 'Model S'), 'in120032');
insert into assessment_flaw(assessment_id, flaw_id) values((select assessment.id from assessment, vehicle, customer where assessment.vehicle_id = vehicle.id and vehicle.customer_id = customer.id and customer.name like 'Simon Lammer' and vehicle.model = 'Model S'), (select flaw.id from flaw where flaw.description like 'Lichterfehlfunktion'));
insert into assessment_flaw(assessment_id, flaw_id) values((select assessment.id from assessment, vehicle, customer where assessment.vehicle_id = vehicle.id and vehicle.customer_id = customer.id and customer.name like 'Simon Lammer' and vehicle.model = 'Model S'), (select flaw.id from flaw where flaw.description like 'Lichterfehlfunktion'));
delete from assessment_flaw where assessment_flaw.assessment_id = (select assessment.id from assessment, vehicle, customer where assessment.vehicle_id = vehicle.id and vehicle.customer_id = customer.id and customer.name like 'Simon Lammer' and vehicle.model = 'Model S' fetch next 1 rows only);

insert into assessment(vehicle_id, editor) values((select vehicle.id from vehicle, customer where vehicle.customer_id = customer.id and customer.name like 'Simon Lammer' and vehicle.model = 'Wrangler'), 'in120032');
insert into assessment_flaw(assessment_id, flaw_id) values((select assessment.id from assessment, vehicle, customer where assessment.vehicle_id = vehicle.id and vehicle.customer_id = customer.id and customer.name like 'Simon Lammer' and vehicle.model = 'Wrangler'), (select flaw.id from flaw where flaw.description like 'Bremsscheiben abgenutzt'));
insert into assessment_flaw(assessment_id, flaw_id) values((select assessment.id from assessment, vehicle, customer where assessment.vehicle_id = vehicle.id and vehicle.customer_id = customer.id and customer.name like 'Simon Lammer' and vehicle.model = 'Wrangler'), (select flaw.id from flaw where flaw.description like 'Achseneinstellung nicht korrekt'));

-- SELECTS
select * from customer
--    where customer.name like 'Simon Lammer'
;

select * from vehicle_view;

select vehicle.id from vehicle, customer where vehicle.customer_id = customer.id and customer.name like 'Simon Lammer' and vehicle.model = 'Model S';

select * from assessment_view;

select * from flaw;

select * from assessment_flaw_view;
```

---

Update 1 - To clarify my question:
I know that the following line is causing the error:

```
 delete from assessment_flaw where assessment_flaw.assessment_id = (select assessment.id from assessment, vehicle, customer where assessment.vehicle_id = vehicle.id and vehicle.customer_id = customer.id and customer.name like 'Simon Lammer' and vehicle.model = 'Model S' fetch next 1 rows only);
```

As I understand it, the error is being caused by this delete

```
1. triggering gen_ids_assessment_flaw which in turn
2. updates assessment and thus 
3. triggers gen_ids_assessment of which the update part
4. queries assessment_flaw
-> mutating table.
```

The question is: Why doesn't insertion cause the same error?

```
insert into assessment_flaw(assessment_id, flaw_id) values((select assessment.id from assessment, vehicle, customer where assessment.vehicle_id = vehicle.id and vehicle.customer_id = customer.id and customer.name like 'Simon Lammer' and vehicle.model = 'Model S'), (select flaw.id from flaw where flaw.description like 'Lichterfehlfunktion'));
```

On execution the is insert is

```
1. triggering gen_ids_assessment_flaw which in turn
2. updates assessment and thus 
3. triggers gen_ids_assessment of which the update part
4. queries assessment_flaw
-> NO mutating table.
```

here are the two triggers of importance:

```
create or replace trigger gen_ids_assessment
before insert or update on assessment
for each row
declare
    n number;
    bp assessment.brakepower%type;
    tmp number;
begin
    if inserting then
        select ids.nextval into n from dual;
        -- id
        :new.id := n;

        -- brakepower
        select ROUND(vehicle.weight / vehicle.brakepower,2) into bp from vehicle where vehicle.id = :new.vehicle_id;
        :new.brakepower := bp;
    elsif updating then
        if :new.id != :old.id then
            raise_application_error(-20002, 'ID ist unveraenderlich konstant !!!');
        end if;

        -- ok?
        dbms_output.put_line('gen_assessment_result before ok?');
        :new.result := 1;
        select COUNT(*) into tmp from assessment_flaw, flaw where assessment_flaw.assessment_id = :new.id and assessment_flaw.flaw_id = flaw.id and flaw.rank = 1;
        if tmp > 2 then
            :new.result := -1;
        end if;
        select COUNT(*) into tmp from assessment_flaw, flaw where assessment_flaw.assessment_id = :new.id and assessment_flaw.flaw_id = flaw.id and flaw.rank != 1;
        if tmp > 0  then
            :new.result := -1;
        end if;
        dbms_output.put_line('gen_assessment_result after ok?');
    end if;
end;
/

create or replace trigger gen_ids_assessment_flaw
before insert or delete or update on assessment_flaw
for each row
declare
    n number;
begin
    if inserting then
        select ids.nextval into n from dual;
        :new.id := n;

        dbms_output.put_line('flaws-count++ on assessment ' || :new.assessment_id);
        update assessment set assessment.flaws = assessment.flaws + 1 where assessment.id = :new.assessment_id;
    elsif deleting then
        dbms_output.put_line('flaws-count-- on assessment ' || :new.assessment_id);
        update assessment set assessment.flaws = assessment.flaws - 1 where assessment.id = :old.assessment_id;
    elsif updating then
        raise_application_error(-20002, 'Entitaet ist unveraenderlich konstant !!!');
    end if;
end;
/
```

Comment: There's no need to keep a counter in assessment as you can query the tables and determine the assessment_flaw count whenever you need it.

Comment: I'll probably delete the column and create a view that does the trick, but I'm still curious as to why the error occurs on deletion while insertion is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

You get the error because:

```
1 You delete assessment_flaw.
2 Trigger on assessment_flaw updates assessment.
3 Trigger on assessment queries assessment_flaw  <<< mutating table.
```

You cannot query the table you are inserting, updating, deleting from within a trigger.

Comment: But why does it allow me to insert rows?

Comment: Read my answer and have a closer look at the trigger on assessment.

Comment: Got it? On insert there is no query on assesment_flaw but on update there is.

Comment: Sorry if I am being stupid here, but i still don't understand why inserting works. to use your list: 1. insert assessment_flaw -> 2. trigger on assessment_flaw updates assessment -> 3. trigger on assessment queries assessment_flaw <<< somehow not mutating table

Comment: trigger gen_ids_assessment.  If inserting NO query on assessment_flaw, NO error. If updating query on assessment_flaw, ERROR.

Comment: I'm inserting/deleting into/from assessment_flaw which has a trigger that updates assessment (which has a trigger that queries assessment_flaw)

Comment: Yes but only when that triggers actually queries assessment_flaw you will get the error. And that only happens in the on update part of the trigger.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130697/discussion-between-evildevil-and-rene).